# Variable Substitution In Angular7 Binding

Tags: angular7

How can I replace the variable when binding in angular7
Suppose I have string "WelCome  to my site"
When binding it should display
WelCome Mike to my site

Comment: it should be done on the html end not in the js component.

Answer (score 0):

You should to use variable in your html template, like {{welcomeMsg}}, and build this string in .ts component (if you are using typescript).

```js
welcomeMsg = "Welcome to my site"; // default value
```

And When application will know usernmae or whatever you need, just change this value as you wish:

```js
...
welcomeMsg = "Welcome " + username + " to my Site.";
...
```

Html template will be updated with the new value.

Or the second opportunity is to use more flexible variable like:

```html
<div>
Welcome {{usename}} to my Site!
</div>
```

When the username variable will be filled with some of the value it will be automatically added to the welcome message.

Comment: I want 
let name = "Mike";

let multi = `hello my name is ${name} `;
console.log(multi);

I want similar thing in html end how it is possible when rendering

Comment: So, as I have described: 
you have a name = 'Mike', message = 'welcome to my site '. Html would be: <span>{{message}} {{name}}</span>

Comment: does it not possible like in C# we have string.format() function which replace the placeholder values ?

Comment: You may use replace() on string function, more you will find on google :)

Comment: But why not there is function like we have in C# for formatting ?
because if we have multiple value to replace then we need to use multiple time replace.

Comment: Maybe because this is not c# ?

Comment: I know it is not C# but I think there should be some ways to replace the place holder values , just think of it , it is commonly used method

Comment: Yes, and I have showed it to you in answer. More info you can simply find in the google :)

Comment: I think we can suggest to the angular community to raise voice for this method ?

Answer (score 0):

if apart from the name the text remain same  and to bind in html then the preferable way in html :-

```
<div>
Welcome {{_userName}} to my Site!
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML file you can write as follows:

```
<div>
<h1>
WelCome {{username}} to my site!
</h1>
</div>
```

and if you are using ts file (TypeScript) you can initialize the username over there.

```
export class AppComponent {
  username= 'Mike';
}
```

hope this helps you.